# Issue cannot be found when trying to add existing issue to epic

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to add issue to epic.
Here I found documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/epics/manage_epics.html#add-an-existing-issue-to-an-epic

but when I click `Add` and then `Add existsing issue` and paste issue link then it says:
`Issue cannot be found.` I also tried putting `#1`

No idea why it doesn't work, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried starting to type the title?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention it. I tried typing issue title like it says in documentation but still without success